# Assistance/Directions/Documentation needed for merging Document in DocuSign that are originating from Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

Our team is currently working on a project where we need to implement a feature to merge multiple documents using DocuSign. The specific requirements are as follows:

1. **Button Creation:**

   - Create a custom button on the Salesforce Contact Record named "Merge Document."
2. **Document Retrieval:**

   - Upon clicking the "Merge Document" button, we need to fetch documents from the Files related object for the respective Salesforce Contact Record.
3. **DocuSign API Integration:**

   - Send the fetched documents to DocuSign through the DocuSign API for processing.
4. **Document Merging:**

   - Have the documents merged in DocuSign as an envelope. It's crucial to note that we are not requiring any e-signature; we are solely interested in the feature to merge multiple documents.
5. **Return Merged Document to Salesforce:**

   - After the merging process in DocuSign, we need to receive the merged document back as an envelope and store it in the Files related object for the associated Salesforce Contact Record.

Thank you

Assistance/Directions/Documentation

Answer (score 0):

All of what you listed (1,2,3,4 & 5) can be done by our out-of-the-box [DocuSign eSignature for Salesforce app](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001taX4EAI) which you can find on the Salesforce App Exchange.

For documentation on :

1. https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/How-to-Create-a-SalesForce-Custom-Button?language=en_US
2. https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=bpg1586134377111&topicId=wqx1612162988070.html&_LANG=enus
3. https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=bpg1586134377111&topicId=wbn1686090714552.html&_LANG=enus
4. https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=srl1586134368658&topicId=jdl1611042391715.html&_LANG=de
5. https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/DocuSign-for-Salesforce-Adding-Completed-Documents-to-the-Notes-and-Attachments-New?language=en_US&rsc_301

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this process by using ApexToolkit. To implement the process, you first need to install the DocuSign Apps Launcher (DAL) managed package into your Salesforce organization and then write the Apex code that calls the Apex Toolkit method: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/

To create the custom button on your Salesforce org, write the Lwc code that triggers the Apex class. Once you write all the Apex codes needed for document retrieval and send the envelope, you can get the document by DocuSign Connect. Connect is a webhook service that writes back the document or any other data when the envelope status is changed. You can implement Connect through ApexToolkit following the "Document and data writeback" section on this post: https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/whats-new-summer-21-apex-toolkit